# ArrayList is returning duplicate values instead of listing out all values

Tags: java, arraylist

When I run my code its meant to display the playCount of each AudioFile in descending order. it can manage this if all of the playCounts are unique however if two playCounts are the same it will just return the same AudioFile twice instead of the two seperate AudioFiles

I am still quite new so i apologize if the mistake is very obvious or i haven't explained properly

This is for a HomeWork Assignment so for ArrayList i am only limited to get,  add,  size  and  remove  methods as well as i can`t include any external libraries other than Scanner and ArrayList

This is my code which relates to the issue

Top 10 Method

```
public String topTen() {
        int[] playcount = new int[audioData.size()];
        if (audioData.size() <= 0) {
            System.out.println("\nNothing here to display\n");
            return null;
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < audioData.size(); index++) {
            playcount[index] = audioData.get(index).getPlayCount();
        }
        bubbleSort(playcount, false);
        if (audioData != null) {
            System.out.println("\nThese are your top 10 tracks\n");
            if (playcount.length < 10) {
                display(playcount);
            } else if (playcount.length >= 10) {
                display(playcount, 10);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Display for less than 10 AudioFiles

```
private void display(int data[]) {
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {

            for (int index = 0; index < audioData.size(); index++) {

                AudioFile audio = searchPlay(audioData.get(index).getPlayCount());
                System.out.println("Code: " + audio.getCode() + ", " + "Title: " + audio.getTitle() + ", " + "Plays: "
                        + audio.getPlayCount() + "\n");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No data to display.\n");
        }
    }
```

Display for 10 or more AudioFiles

```
private void display(int data[], int count) {
        if (data != null && data.length > 0 && data.length >= count && count > 0) {

            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {

                AudioFile audio = searchPlay(data[index]);
                System.out.println("Code: " + audio.getCode() + ", " + "Title: " + audio.getTitle() + ", " + "Plays: "
                        + audio.getPlayCount());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No data to display.\n");
        }
    }
```

Sorting playCount in desc order

```
private void bubbleSort(int[] data, boolean ascending) {
        int swaps;
        do {
            swaps = 0;
            for (int index = 0; index < data.length - 1; index++) {
                if (data[index] > data[index + 1] && ascending || data[index] < data[index + 1] && !ascending) {
                    int temp = data[index];
                    data[index] = data[index + 1];
                    data[index + 1] = temp;
                    swaps++;
                }
            }
        } while (swaps > 0);
    }
```

```
private AudioFile searchPlay(int id) {
        AudioFile target = null;
        for (int index = 0; index < audioData.size(); index++) {
            AudioFile audio = audioData.get(index);
            if (audio.getPlayCount() == id) {
                target = audio;
                
                break;
            }
        }
        return target;
    }
```

Comment: You're using `searchPlay` to look up things by play count, but there's no way `searchPlay` could know to look up different songs with the same count.  It sounds like you might need to sort the original `AudioFile` array instead of just an array of the play counts.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I felt like searchPlay was the issue but Im not sure how Id go about sorting AudioFile so that the playCounts are in desc order

Comment: The same way you sorted the `int[]`, just instead of `data[index] > data[index + 1]`, you may have to do something like `data[index].getPlayCount() > data[index+1].getPlayCount()`.

Comment: I tried doing that but it just returns with index 12 out of bounds for length 12  `private void bubbleSort(int[] data, boolean ascending) {
  int swaps;
  do {
   swaps = 0;
   for (int index = 0; index < data.length - 1; index++) {
    if (audioData.get(data[index]).getPlayCount() > audioData.get(data[index+1]).getPlayCount() && ascending || audioData.get(data[index]).getPlayCount() < audioData.get(data[index+1]).getPlayCount() && !ascending) {
     int temp = data[index];
     data[index] = data[index + 1];
     data[index + 1] = temp;
     swaps++;
}}} while (swaps > 0);}`

Comment: is it easier to update the code in my question rather than copying it all into the comment

Comment: Presumably you wouldn't want to pass an `int[]` to this method anymore, but you'd want to pass an `AudioData[]`, or switch to the `List<AudioData>`.